# KiCad Schematic Check

Tags: pcb, esp32, gpio, kicad

I just want to make sure that the schematic I had made was done so correctly, specifically the button configuration. I want a 10 kohm pull-down for each button so I want to make sure that I had routed the buttons to the GPIO correctly.

Also will the RGB LED have a common anode like I have and use the `setColor()` function from the RGB library to control the illuminated color? Pretty much SW1 is to activate the BLE sequence and SW2 is for changing the current state of the board (which will be indicated by the LEDs). Both switches need to wake up the ESP from deep sleep so they have to be on GPIO0-GPIO5.

[image: Updated KiCAD Schematic]

[image: KiCAD Schematic (zoomed in)]

[image: Updated LED Footprint]

[image: ERC Error]

Comment: Could you post a higher-resolution image of your diagram?  Much of the writing is illegible.

Comment: Posted a new zoomed in pic, hope this helps

Comment: Your microcontroller's ground isn't connected to the power supply ground, so it won't work right.

Comment: I see, but if I use the GND of U2 (the boost converter) and route it to where the LED and GND of the mcu meet (where the power flag is), that would work since the power supply is the converter?

Comment: Is the ESP a module with decoupling capacitors or just the raw IC?

Comment: Your R and G and B LEDs are in parallel with only a single connection to the CPU -- they can't be controlled individually.  Also: your batteries are connected through resistors: what is this for?

Comment: @winny it is just the raw IC

Comment: @jonathanjo so for the LEDs, each R, G, and B would have its own connection to gpio? And the resistor anre in series with the batteries to reduce the equivalent current between the batteries since they are in parallel

Comment: Re LEDs: yes, each needs its own resistor and its own GPIO pin.  Resistors often slightly different for the different Vf of the different colours.  Re batteries: either use batteries which are from the same packet, or better yet just a bigger battery.  The resistors are just wasting power in what appears to be designed as nearly-no-current-until-woken device.

Comment: @jonathanjo I will be using batteries from the same pack! I cannot get a bigger battery however cuz the space I have to work with is really small (maximum 16mm diameter and 4mm height). As for the LEDs, I was looking at the datasheet and the datasheet has a common anode where all 3 colors go into 1 input. The link for the datasheet can be found on digikey: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/everlight-electronics-co-ltd/EAST1616RGBB4/8510361

Comment: @jonathanjo I added a picture of the LED (taken by snapEDA) and the footprint has 3 pads for GND and 1 pad for the input which suggests that all 3 colors share the same gpio

Comment: LED: See diagram, datasheet p2.  pin 4 to 3v3.  Pin 1 through a resistor to GPIO.  Pin 2 through another resistor to another GPIO.  Pin 3 through third resistor to third GPIO.  Unless you use three GPIO pins you can't send separate signals to the three LEDs.

Comment: @jonathanjo I updated the pictures with the updated PCB following your suggestions. Am I on the right track? I updated the footprint to where pin 4 is 3v3 and all the others go to a resistor which goes to its own gpio. I also added a route from the GND of the converter to the GND of the mcu (also the GND from the battery to the GND of the converter)

Comment: You diagram shows an LED device with 6 pins; your datasheet only has four.

Comment: i believe that is why there was a common anode. Since there are only 4 pins on the datasheet, there is only 1 gpio input instead of 3 as the diagram in the datasheet suggests. Each color would then be parallel to one another and there would be only 1 resistor for all three colors?

Comment: I can only repeat what I said before.  If you're using the device of the datasheet you listed, it *must* be wired the way I described, with three resistors and three GPIO pins, and the common anodes (on pin 4) to 3v3.

Comment: Then you need decoupling capacitor(s) for it. Your LEDs needs one pin per LED and separate resistors for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Input Power pin not driven by any Output Power pins" error's cause is self-descriptive: if there are Input Power pins, there should be an Output Power pin connected to the same net. ERC picks it up because it may indicate a problem.

In your particular case, I think that perhaps the component symbol for U2 has a wrong pin type for the VOUT pin. It should be Output Power, as the ERC suggests.

The PWR_FLAG on the GND net is appropriate and I'm glad you've figured it out :)